# Reverse with argument ('')not found. Variable doesnt work

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't figure out why my url doesn't work together with my variable. This way

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'p4_descriptor_update' 1 form.instance.pk %}" class="js-descriptor-update-form">
```

it works, but this

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'p4_descriptor_update' projectid form.instance.pk %}" class="js-descriptor-update-form">
```

results in:

> Reverse for 'p4_descriptor_update' with a rguments '('', 249)' not
>   found. 2 pattern(s) tried

I can call `{{ projectid }}` in my template and it shows the correct number (which is 1)

urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/p4_descriptor_update/$', views.p4_descriptor_update, name='p4_descriptor_update'),
```

views.py

```
class phase4 (APIView):

    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'szenario/phase4.html'

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        projectid = id
        context = {... 'projectid': projectid}
        return Response(context)
```

Not sure if relevant, but the button is not in the main template but included with `{% incldue .. %}`. If needed i can add the JS or any further information needed.

Comment: `projectid` n'a pas été envoyé via le contexte, use `get_context_data()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword syntax:

```
{% url 'p4_descriptor_update' id=projectid pk=form.instance.pk %}
```

More info can be found in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)